# How to derive function of complex variable for a given expression?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose I have a complex-valued expression such as $w(z) = \frac{y}{x}.$ How can I derive the means of representing this expression in terms of $z$ and $\bar{z}$? I'm guessing I might need the Cauchy-Riemann equations if not algebra, but it would be nice to have a more general method for problems like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$W(z)=\frac{y}{x}=-i\frac{z-\bar z}{z+\bar z}$$

Comment: Excellent...I see you added that "-i" in front. :)  I'm about to edit and include the "-" in mine. :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace every occurrence of $x$ with $\frac12 (z + \bar{z})$; replace every occurrence of $y$ with $\frac1{2i}(z-\bar{z})$.

In your example, you get
\begin{align}
w(z) &= \frac yx \\
&= \frac{\frac1{2i}(z-\bar{z})}{\frac12 (z + \bar{z})} \\
&= \frac{\frac1{i}(z-\bar{z})}{ (z + \bar{z})} \\
&= -i\frac{(z-\bar{z})}{ (z + \bar{z})} \\
\end{align}